# PHP5.6 - "The php-devel package is required for use of this command" but "Package php-devel-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version"

Tags: php, pecl

Docker container running remi php 5.6 at /opt/rh/rh-php56

Trying to run a pecl package (ssh2) install but output says

```
Can't find PHP headers in /opt/rh/rh-php56/root/usr/include/php
The php-devel package is required for use of this command.
ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

however get this when installing it:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.centos.org
 * extras: mirror.centos.org
 * updates: mirror.centos.org
Package php-devel-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

php-pear is already installed

php-devel is already installed

/opt/rh/rh-php56/root/usr/include/php folder is empty

Comment: You may need to remove it and re-install it. It's version `php-devel-5.4`, which doesn't match with php 5.6. As a note, both are extremely outdated, and you should think about upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

> Docker container running remi php 5.6 at /opt/rh/rh-php56

You are not using "remi" packages but official rh-php56 collection.

As you are using **rh-php56** packages, you need the **rh-php56-php-devel** packages (the message is indeed wrong, but won't be fixed)

**WARNINGS**:

- **CentOS 7** is close to its end of life in about 1 year, see [End dates are coming for CentOS Stream 8 and CentOS Linux 7](https://blog.centos.org/2023/04/end-dates-are-coming-for-centos-stream-8-and-centos-linux-7/)
- **rh-php56** collection has reached its end of life in 2017, so is not maintained anymore, and is very insecure, see [Product Life Cycle of Red Hat Software Collections for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/rhscl-rhel7)

I recommend you update your image to use a modern distro (EL-8 or EL-9) and use a maintained PHP stack.

- EL-8 has PHP 7.4/8.0 in the official repository
- EL-9 has PHP 8.0/8.1 in the official repository

Remi repository provides more versions and more extensions, see the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) instructions for proper configuration/usage, and for available versions.